# Working with file (open,write,close) in nested loops

Tags: python

I want to generate two digit counter and write them in a file and do something for each instance. Each digit is actually a byte represented by a hex value. So, I want to

0- Open the file for write

1- Generate `0x00,0x00`

2- write that in a file.

3- Close the file and process it

and this continues for `0x00,0x01` and `0x00,0x02` and ... and `0x01,0x00` until `0xff,0xff`.

I have written a sample like this

```
for i in range(2):
    f = open("file.txt", "w")
    f.write("0x{:02x},".format(i))
    for j in range(3):
        f.write("0x{:02x}".format(j))
        f.close()
        # run a cmd and pass this file as an argument
```

Ranges should be 256 in the final script. Nonetheless, problem is that, when the file is closed in the inner loop, it can not be ready for the second digit in the next inner iteration. Therefore, that code only works for i=j=0 and when i=0,j=1 it is unable to write the hex value into the file.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Why not open it before the nested loop and close it after?

Comment: You’re closing the file before the second iteration close it after the loops

Comment: Because I want to be sure that cmd is reading the file correctly. The cmd is run in the inner loop. If I don't close the file, maybe something goes wrong (such as not flushing the last characters). Isn't it?

Comment: Move the two lines opening and writing `f` from the outer loop to the inner loop.

Comment: Why don't you just pipe the string to said proccess instead of going through a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, at the end of the first j-loop, you close the file but don't open it again. You should open and close it in the same loop :

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        f = open("file.txt", "w+")
        f.write("0x{:02x},".format(i))
        f.write("0x{:02x}".format(j))
        f.close()
        # run a cmd and pass this file as an argument
```

Comment: "w+" will overwrite the content at each iteration, is this what OP wants ? + you should use `with` blocks to read/write files

Comment: Yes. I want to write new file every time.

Comment: Oh, you should include that in your question then.

Comment: There's a `format()` call for the filename with no placeholders in the string.  Also one `write()` would be sufficient if you format both values into one string.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the format in filename. I edited that

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any worry about file not being written before the next iteration, because buffer is there to make sure that you do not loose anything. When you write to a file, even in a simple loop, everything will be written in order by the time you close your file. Closing and opening the file to make sure that all was written is firstly hugely inefficient, secondly unnecessary.

You may simply go along this lines:

```
with open("file.txt", "w+") as f:
    for i in range(2):
        f.write("0x{:02x},".format(i))
        for j in range(3):
            f.write("0x{:02x}".format(j))
```

If you still insist on forcing the io operation to be initiated, you may use [file.flush()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush).

==EDIT==

I kinda misunderstood what you ment there, but I still believe that opening and closing isn't the way to go. Instead I would propose to pass the string as an argument for said script. But if you insist on the file, then you may go like this:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in range(2):
        f.seek(0)
        f.write("0x{:02x},".format(i))
        for j in range(3):
            f.write("0x{:02x}".format(j))
            f.flush()
            #do your cmd, I hope it opens the file in read mode.
```

I gave up timing it after few minutes:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(3): f = open("file.txt", "w"); f.write("test"); f.close()')
```

But this went quite quickly:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('for i in range(3): f.seek(0); f.write("test"); f.flush()', setup = 'f = open("file.txt", "w")')

23.751912800013088
```

Comment: Does the file always contains one line or I will see `0x00,0x00\n0x00,0x01\n...0xff,0xff` at the end?

Comment: It will contain everything. If you really inisit on it having a single line file instead of piping you may use `file.seek(0)` with `file.write()` and `file.flush()` in that order. It will be muuuch more efficient then opening and closing the file.I suppose

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting two loops you could also use `itertools.product()` to generate the values:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import product


def main():
    for i, j in product(range(256), repeat=2):
        with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write(f'0x{i:02x},0x{j:02x}\n')
        # run a cmd and pass this file as an argument


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```